Is there a way to restart a modified addon without restarting blender?
This was answered 10 Years ago. Unfortunately, it doesnt work anymore.
It should be a simple console command:
bpy.ops.script.reload()

However, it only reloads the __init__​.py from the addon, all other files are not reload. Also, deleting all files in the __pycache__-folder doesnt help. I still have to always restart Blender, which makes developing multi-file addons pretty tedious.
How can you do it?

Do you know the workflow from within vs code using Jaques Lucks vs code addon?

@Leander No, my workflow is gedit and blender.

Note: You can use the little apostrophe looking symbol on your keyboard (usually on the same key as ~) to denote code and things you don’t want formatted in StackExchange and GitHub. Here, the double underscore surrounding init has been interpreted as instructions to make it bold. Add the apostrophe thingies on either side to fix this.

@TheLabCat Apostrophe/SingleQuote (0x27) didnt work.  0xB4 (Acute) did at least not remove the underscores.

@leander zero width spacer works. Those are filenames, not commands.

According to https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/78500 There is a recent confirmed bug with the reload()-function.
Script that execute a ​__init__.py dont seem to reload imported modules. This seems to be exactly the issue here, as my changes wont get updated with the mentioned bpy.ops.script.reload().

IMHO the best workflow is using VS Code https://youtu.be/YUytEtaVrrc?si=EDHIYLyLaS86M-f1 but this ones for Windows. However VS Code also works for Linux. Then I made myself a reusable addon template repository https://github.com/hkunz/blender-addon-template
